# print method for list changes values of items

Tags: python, list

I have problem with printing `list`. `random_itemst_stac` contains list of items (`cards`). Prints of elements and indexes in for loop works perfect but when I print a whole array there are X set for others items - it's strange.

`Card` class:

```
class Card(object):

    def __init__(self, r=0):
        self.__rank=0
        self.__hidden= False
        if type(r) == str:
            if r in 'J':
                self.__rank = 11  # Jack
            elif r in 'Q':
                self.__rank = 12  # Queen
            elif r in 'K':
                self.__rank = 13  # King
            elif r in 'A':
                self.__rank = 1   # Ace
        elif type(r) == int:
            if 1 <= r <= 14:
                self.__rank = r

    def hideCard(self, val):
        self.__hidden= val

    def isCardHidden(self):
        return self.__hidden

    def setRank(self, r):
        self.__rank = r

    def getRank(self):
        return self.__rank

    def getValue(self):
        """(Jack, Queen, King = 10), Ace = 1, reszta 2-10"""
        if self.__rank <= 10:
            return self.__rank
        else:
            return 10

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.__hidden:
            return "X".rjust(3)
        else:
            nameString = "blk A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K"  # 'blk' for blank, i.e. no karty
            nameList = nameString.split()
            return (nameList[self.__rank]).rjust(3)
```

And here is method to create list of lists (super_matrix):
random_items_stack contains CARD objects.
I need also show only last card in row (others should be Hidden - X sign returned by *`repr`*

```
def setup():

    super_matrix= [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

    for x in range(54):
        newItem= random_items_stack .pop()
        super_matrix[x%10].append(newItem)

    for y in range(10):
        for z in range(0, len(plansza[y])):
            if(z == (len(plansza[y])-1)):
                print('index:')
                print(y,z)
                print('showed:')
                plansza[y][z].hideCard(False)
                print(plansza[y][z])
            else:
                print('index:')
                print(y,z)
                print('hidden:')
                plansza[y][z].hideCard(True)
                print(plansza[y][z])
    print(super_matrix)
```

Fragment of example output:

```
index:
0 0
hidden:
  X
index:
0 1
hidden:
  X
index:
0 2
hidden:
  X
index:
0 3
hidden:
  X
index:
0 4
hidden:
  X
index:
0 5
showed:
  9
index:
1 0
hidden:
  X
index:
1 1
hidden:
  X
index:
1 2
hidden:
  X
index:
1 3
hidden:
  X
index:
1 4
hidden:
  X
index:
1 5
showed:
  8
index:
2 0
hidden:
  X
index:
2 1
hidden:
  X
index:
2 2
hidden:
  X
index:
2 3
hidden:
  X
index:
2 4
hidden:
  X
index:
2 5
showed:
  J
index:
3 0
hidden:
  X

[[  X,   X,   X,   X,   X,   X], [  X,   X,   X,   X,   X,   X], [  X,   2,   X,   2,   X,   J], [  X,   X,   X,   X,   X,   X], [  2,   X,   X,   X,   X], [  X,   X,   X,   X,   X], [  J,   X,   X,   X,   X], [  X,   X,   X,   X,   X], [  X,   X,   X,   X,   J], [  X,   X,   X,   X,   2]]
```

Comment: can you post [mcve] http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?
'random_items_stack' is not defined

Comment: What is plansza? Is it super_matrix?

Comment: @Delimitry yes, sory for my mistake during translation.

Comment: I would guess that the real problem is that something you were expecting to make a copy doesn't actually make a copy, so you have the same `Card` objects sitting around in two data structures. When you change a `Card` in one data structure, the change is visible in the other.

Comment: @matcheek random_items_stack is not important here, the problem is that when I am adding element to list and dipslays it works great, but finally when i print list it prints some crazy s***

Comment: if you don't post a minimal verifiable working example you reduce your chances to get the question answered, that's for sure.

Comment: @user2357112 her is initialization of deck of card (its source for random_itemst_stac):  self.__talia = 8 * [Card(j) for j in range(1,14)]

Comment: Yup, that's definitely not making the copies you're expecting it to. You'll find that `self.__talia[0] is self.talia[13]`, along with other similar problems. List multiplication just copies references; it won't copy the actual `Card` objects. You need to initialize that as `[Card(j) for _ in range(8) for j in range(1, 14)]`.

Comment: @user2357112 it works and i understand now how multiply sign works in this case - really thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this comment:

> @user2357112 her is initialization of deck of card (its source for random_itemst_stac): self.__talia = 8 * [Card(j) for j in range(1,14)]

This means that you have multiple references to the same cards in your random_itemst_stac.

You should be making a new `Card` for each card you need in your random stack instead of multiplying a list.

So something like:

```
self.__talia = [Card(j%13+1) for j in range(13*8)]
```

if you want each card 1-13, 8 times.